# Identifying order of a group from three pieces of information about its' subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Suppose $G$ is a cyclic group that has exactly three different subgroups: The trivial one, a subgroup of order $7$ and $G$ itself. What is the order of $G$?

What is the idea here?

Comment: They're all cyclic.

Comment: I don't believe we've learned Lagrange here.

Comment: Lagrange says that the order of a subgroup divides the order of the group. I am sure you had this.

Comment: And if the group is cyclic, then for each prime divisor $d$ of $|G|$ we have a subgroup of order $d$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For finite cyclic groups, there is a bijection between subgroups of $G$ and divisors of $|G|$.

Since $G$ is cyclic, the statement is equivalent to saying that $|G|$ has exactly three divisors: $1$, $7$ and $|G|$ itself. So $|G| = 7^2$.

Comment: "For finite cyclic groups, there is a bijection between subgroups of $G$ and divisors of $|G|$." What is this theory? Still new to the course

Comment: @TheNotMe this is the well-known structure theorem for finite cyclic froups https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroups_of_cyclic_groups#Finite_cyclic_groups